# Can a Google Apps script update a spreadsheet before it terminates?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to see changes to a Google Spreadsheet made by an Apps Script while the script is still running?

It appears to me that if a Google Apps script makes several modifications to a spreadsheet, they all take effect, or at least they all LOOK (on screen) like they take effect only when the script terminates.

Comment: Have you tried an operation, pause for one second, watch the screen, try an operation... Repeat?

Comment: Try `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spreadsheetapp.flush()` is the answer.

Thank you Sandy Good.  Sorry I can't vote up your comment.